# Declare Matlab object in VB.net without late binding

Tags: vb.net, matlab

I need to execute a Matlab function from vb.net. After much searching, the only examples that I can find use late binding; http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-a-matlab-function-from-visual-basic-net-client.html

I have option strict turned on, so I can not declare the variable "Matlab" as type 'object'.
What is the actual object type that I need to be using?

Comment: I would think that the *only* type you could use was that of _Object_.

Comment: Ok, I see now that it's the mathlab object causing the problem. I think that the only way is to turn off strict.